# MVC 5 site - If I always validate input do I need AntiXSS library?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC 5 site. Out of the box it validates all input and prevents html being entered by users (and thus, I assume, XSS attacks).

Right?

Is there any reason to install the AntiXSS library if I have no requirement to allow users to enter HTML into the site?

I have found a lot of information that dances round this subject but nothing that explicitly answers this question.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't always count on ASP.NET blocking dangerous form values. For example, in an AJAX call, if you're posting form-encoded values, it'll catch it, but if you're posting JSON, it'll let HTML slip through.

Answer (score -2):

According to my research it is not needed because for example if you write html or script in input after post it to action an error appear like this:

```
 **"A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (Name=\"<b> test for AntiXSS </b>\").""**
```

but what happen if u want to use HTML Editor Like tinymon or wysiwyg .this is where u can use this library.although i offer u to log all event in your webApplication